# Select rows in dataframes inside a list then append to another dataframe inside another list

Tags: pandas, indexing, nested-loops, data-transform

I have daily stock data inside a list of n dataframes (each stock has its own dataframe). I want to select m rows on equal time intervals from each dataframe and append them to dataframes inside another list. Basically the new list should have m dataframes - which is the number the number of days, and each dataframe length n - the number of stocks.
I tried with nested for loops but it just didn't work

```
cross_section = []
cross_sections_list = []

for m in range(0, len(datalist[0]), 100):    
    for n in range(len(datalist)):
        cross_section.append(datalist[n].iloc[m])
        cross_sections_list.append(cross_section)
```

this code didnt do anything. my machine just stacked on it. if there is another way like multiindexing for example I would love trying it too.

For example

input:

```
[
             Adj Close   Ticker  
 Date                           
 2020-06-01  321.850006   AAPL  
 2020-06-02  323.339996   AAPL  
 2020-06-03  325.119995   AAPL  
 2020-06-04  322.320007   AAPL  
 2020-06-05  331.500000   AAPL  
 2020-06-08  333.459991   AAPL  
 2020-06-09  343.989990   AAPL  
 2020-06-10  352.839996   AAPL  ,

             Adj Close    Ticker  
 Date                           
 2020-06-01  182.830002   MSFT  
 2020-06-02  184.910004   MSFT  
 2020-06-03  185.360001   MSFT  
 2020-06-04  182.919998   MSFT  
 2020-06-05  187.199997   MSFT  
 2020-06-08  188.360001   MSFT  
 2020-06-09  189.800003   MSFT  
 2020-06-10  196.839996   MSFT  ]
```

output:

```
 [
             Adj Close   Ticker  
 Date                           
 2020-06-01  321.850006   AAPL  
 2020-06-01  182.830002   MSFT  ,

             Adj Close   Ticker  
 Date                           
 2020-06-03  325.119995   AAPL  
 2020-06-03  185.360001   MSFT  ,

             Adj Close   Ticker  
 Date                           
 2020-06-05  331.500000   AAPL  
 2020-06-05  187.199997   MSFT  ]
```

and so on.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean to have the step set at 100?

Comment: Please add an example of data input and expected output.

Comment: user13802115, Yes

Comment: Edgar Ramirez, done it. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly clear what you want, but here is some code that hopefully helps.

```
list_of_df = [] #list of all the df's

alldf = pd.concat(list_of_df) #brings all df's into one df

list_of_grouped = [y for x, y in alldf.groupby('Date')] #separates df's by date and puts them in a list

number_of_days = alldf.groupby('Date').ngroups #Total number of groups (Dates)

list_of_Dates = [x for x, y in alldf.groupby('Date')] #List of all the dates that were grouped

count_of_stocks = []
for i in range(len(list_of_grouped)):
    count_of_stocks.append(len(list_of_grouped[i])) #puts count of each grouped df into a list

zipped = list(zip(list_of_data,count_of_stocks)) #combines the dates and count of stocks in a list to see how many stocks are in each date.
```

Comment: thanks it worked great. I simplified it a bit. all i couldn't do was the 3rd step. will post the answer

Comment: Glad I could help. Please reference the following link on how to close the question out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
data_global = pd.DataFrame()
for i in datalist:
    data_global = data_global.append(i) #first merge all dataframes into one

data_by_date = [i for x, i in data_global.groupby('Date')] #step 2: group the data by date

each_nth_day = []
for i in range(0, len(data_by_date), 21):
    each_nth_day.append(data_by_date[i]) #lastly take each n-th dataframe (21 in this case)
```

thanks for your help user13802115